# How to exit xen domu when using linux terminal

Tags: virtualization, xen, terminal, console

I usually use putty to connect on a xen domus. 
To exit domus after using "xm console", it's ctrl + 5

But how can I exit vm console on linux terminal?

Comment: I think it's a matter of xm, not a matter of client terminal

Answer (score 2):

finally find it:

```
ctrl + alt  + ]
```

Answer (score 0):

`ctrl + shift + ]` works on Oracle VM server release 3.3.1 with xen-tools-4.3.0-55.el6.x86_64

Comment: It might be helpful what `here` is. A different OS?